# Abrindo página exterior sem refresh

Tags: php, html

Como posso mostrar um link ou um div ao clicar em um  sem refresh na página

```
<li>
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#pagesExamples">
                        <i class="pe-7s-gift"></i>
                        <p>Comprar BCC | Buy BCC
                           <b class="caret"></b>
                        </p>
                    </a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="pagesExamples">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="sidebar-mini">BTC</span>
                                    <span class="sidebar-normal">Bitcoin</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Div** que deve aparece ao clicar na span Bitcoin

```
<div class="btn-content-rc">
   <div class="rc-btn-payment"
  data-amount="100" 
  data-iso4217="BRL" 
  data-button="white" 
  data-refer_id="****" 
  data-token="976808fb-********33" 
  data-email_client="****y@gmail.com"> <!-- --> </div>
  <div class="btc-address-rc">
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para uma resposta mais completa seria necessário que você poste algum código da sua página, mas tendo como pressuposto que poderia ser um simples link:

Você precisa inserir alguma âncora no seu HTML.

```
<a href='/oi.php'>Ir para página</a>
```

`href` é um atributo usado para definir para qual *link* uma determinada *tag html* está atrelada, e que o usuário será enviado caso realize uma iteração específica com essa tag.

Exemplo: usuário clica em um link com a tag:

```
<a href="www.google.com">Clique aqui</a>
```

é enviado para a página `www.google.com`.

EDIT:

Para abrir uma página numa parte do site você pode usar o `iframe`, segue uma implementação de exemplo:

```
<div>
  <a id="link">Mostrar página</a>
  <iframe id="myIframe" src="user/login">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('link').onclick = showIframe;

function showIframe(){

  document.getElementById('myIframe').style.display = 'block';
  console.log('called')
}
```

CSS:

```
#myIframe { display:none; }
```

Link para o código funcionando: http://jsfiddle.net/6NZaS/55/

Comment: Entendi amigo. Mas como eu posso abrir outras páginas dentro do meu template ? Ao o usuário clicar, por exemplo, em charts, ele abrir na parte em branco do template

Comment: Editarei o post, por favor, tente responder, se possível.

Comment: @PLINIORODRIGUES Editei minha resposta, e coloquei um código exemplo.